# How do I get Microsoft Script Debugger to work with 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: debugging, windows-7, vbscript, 64-bit

I'm trying to debug some VBScript and normally I'd install the ancient (but free) [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22185) which would work fine on 32-bit XP and 32-bit Windows 7.

However after installing it on 64-bit Windows 7 neither `//d` or `//x` (or even both) actually invoke the debugger any more. The script will happily run as if I've never supplied the option - but that isn't very useful.

Is there anything I can do to get it working? I only use it occasionally to scratch my own itches, so I cannot justify purchasing some commercial tool as a replacement.

Comment: Have you tried running the 32-bit version of WScript at `%windir%\SysWOW64\wscript.exe`?

Comment: the link to ms script debugger no longer links to anything

Comment: The page seems to work for me, once you scroll down past the huge "Windows 10" banner. Worth noting that it's not officially supported on anything later than Windows XP.

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel Can you post this as an answer? The question is still marked as unanswered.

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel: that really would be helpful! The debugging just started working on my 64-bit w10 installation `[Version 10.0.19044.2965]`. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has been removed script debugger from their server. So, you can download it from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bvobcrm39ve1ywn/Microsoft_script_debugger.zip) and try with this. I'm using windows 7 (64-bit) and it's working for me fine.