# Windows 7 vbscript debugging does not work using //X and //D tags

Tags: debugging, vbscript, windows-7-x64

Update:
When I put the tags in I found this:
[How do I get Microsoft Script Debugger to work with 64-bit Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980171/how-do-i-get-microsoft-script-debugger-to-work-with-64-bit-windows-7?rq=1)

The answer there seems to have solved the problem.

Thanks to anyone who looked...
--VS

I have tried installing the MS script debugger (scd10en.exe).
That did not work -- when running my test script using //X //d, it just runs.

I installed visual studio express, and same deal.

I checked the registry key setting for jitdebug and it is set to 1.

I tried using mse7 per this answer:
[How do I debug a stand-alone VBScript script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288043/how-do-i-debug-a-stand-alone-vbscript-script)

When I do this, I get strange behaviour:  No way to step into the code.
Pressing F11, F5 or F10 (step into, start or step over) or any menu or toolbar button merely opens a download dialog apparently from Internet explorer.

The script is dead simple:

```
Option Explicit
stop
WScript.Echo "Hello Dolly"
WScript.Quit
```

I have tried invoking the script as:

```
test.vbs //x //d
cscript test.vbs //x //d
```

and various permutations.

I have looked at VBSEdit, but although I can get it to step through code, even then I cannot invoke it w/ //X //D

Could this be related to the fact that I'm running Windows 7 64-bit?

Is there a solution at all?

Thanks,
--VS

Comment: There are klll 32 and 64 bit versions of everything. Try the 32 bit version as MSSD is a 32 bit program. %windir%\SysWOW64.

Comment: Also `cscript //x script.vbs`

Comment: You said that the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10980171/3357935) resolved your issue, but the question doesn't have any answers.

Comment: If you run cscript as follows:
%windir%\SysWOW64\Cscript.exe <path to script> <parameters if any> //X //D

Then it should work
That was a comment under the linked duplicate, but not an answer.
I have not done this for several months, so can't guarantee that it still works